# How can I prevent SafeAreaProvider from autoHiding the Expo SplashScreen?

Tags: react-native, expo, safeareaview

Wrapping my Expo app with a SafeAreaProvider from react-native-safe-area-context seems to be overriding the functionality of Expo's AppLoading component which prevents autoHiding the SplashScreen.

When I remove the SafeAreaProvider wrapper from the root of my Expo app, the SplashScreen stays visible as expected.

Is there any way to use a SafeAreaProvider that doesn't autoHide Expo's SplashScreen?

```js
<AppLoading
    startAsync={this.getUserAuth}
    onFinish={this.finishLoading}
    autoHideSplash={false}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to do this with a SwitchNavigator.

```js
const SwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        Auth: AuthScreen,
        TabNavigator,
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Auth',
    },
);
```